# Frequency of Digits Appearing in the Decimal Part of $\sqrt 2$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

There's no doubt that the decimal part of $\sqrt 2$ is determined and unique, but do the digits 1~9 appear evenly?

More precisely, suppose we take the first $N$ numbers, count the number of times they occur, and found that the digit $i$ appear $a_i(N)$ times. Then does the probability
$$P_i(N)=\frac{a_i(N)}N$$
converge to $1/10$ for all $i$? If it does, let
$$|P_i(N)-\frac1{10}|\leq C·N^{-\alpha}$$
Can we determine $\alpha$? In other words, how fast does it converge? Is it possible to discuss general transcendental numbers like $\sqrt 3,\pi,e$ all at once?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties_and_examples): It has been an elusive goal to prove the normality of numbers that are not artificially constructed. While $\sqrt{2}, π, \ln(2)$, and $e$ are strongly conjectured to be normal, it is still not known whether they are normal or not.

Comment: For no algebraic irrational number and neither for $e$ , $\pi$ , $\ln(2)$ , $\gamma$ , it is known whether every finite digit string appears.  Even worse, for all those irrationals, we do not know whether a single given digit occurs infinite many often, we cannot even rule out for any of those irrational numbers that it eventually contains only two distinct digits. In short, we know almost nothing about the decimal expansion in the long run.

Comment: Additional remark : For $\gamma$ , we do not even know whether it is irrational. It could even have a terminating decimal expansion.

Comment: All my above numbers are however conjectured to be (absolutely) normal and this is conjectured even for $\gamma$ which is assumed to be transcendental.

Comment: "transcendental numbers like $\sqrt{3}$" , this is not a transcendental number.